# Validação de data com Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, validação

Como fazer validação de data a partir do EditorFor usando jquery? queria verificar se a data digitada pelo usuário, e caso a data que ele digitou seja maior que a data atual, exibir uma mensagem pra ele informando o erro

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control data" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

pensei em fazer um jquery que pega o conteúdo digitado e verifica a data. Alguém pode me ajudar?

com a ajuda de @LucasDeFreitasKauer foi feito este script:

```
$("#DataDeNascimento").on("blur", validarDataDeNascimento);
var validarDataDeNascimento = function () {
    var dataDeNascimentoStr = $("#DataDeNascimento").val();
    var dataDeNascimento = new Date(dataDeNascimentoStr);
    var agora = new Date();
    if (dataDeNascimento > agora) {
        alert("A data de nascimento não pode ser uma data futura.");
    }
};
```

e foi adicionado ao EditorFor o ID **id = "DataDeNascimento"** porém quando perde o focus(blur) não exibe nenhum alerta.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer validar? Poderia explicar melhor o seu problema?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Por que você colocou "**- Pendente**" no título da pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você precisará adicionar um `id` ao campo de data de nascimento:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control data", id = "DataDeNascimento" } })
```

Depois você pode fazer a validação da seguinte forma:

```
$("#DataDeNascimento").on("change", validarDataDeNascimento);

var validarDataDeNascimento = function () { 
    var dataDeNascimentoStr = $("#DataDeNascimento").val();
    var dataDeNascimento = new Date(dataDeNascimentoStr);
    var agora = new Date();

    if (dataDeNascimento > agora) {
        alert("A data de nascimento não pode ser uma data futura.");
    }   
};
```

### Atualizado

Pode ser feito no `onBlur` também. Para isto, será necessário alterar `$("#DataDeNascimento").on("change", validarDataDeNascimento);` por `$("#DataDeNascimento").on("blur", validarDataDeNascimento);`

Comment: se eu quiser fazer a validação quando ele tirar o focus (blur) como faria?

Comment: Substitui a o change por blur. Vou alterar para ti.

Comment: eu tentei isso, não funcionou :\

Comment: pode colocar o erro?

Comment: Dependendo do formato da data que tu espera não funcionará. Precisa ser yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Não exibe erro algum, o padrão da data é pt-br dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Provavelmente é esse o problema! Edite sua pergunta novamente adicionando mais instruções e o código JS que você tentou fazer.

Comment: pergunta editada